# Static and Resources files in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

"By default, all files in the WAR are treated as both static files and resource files, except for JSP files, which are compiled into servlet classes and mapped to URL paths, and files in the WEB-INF/ directory, which are never served as static files and always available to the app as resource files." [Link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files)

Does that mean files that are treated both static files and resource files gets uploaded twice, one copy in the static file server and another copy application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update, each file gets uploaded at most once.